# nib2objc Converting .storyboard to objective-c

Tags: objective-c, xcode, xcode-storyboard

Has anyone ever used nib2objc to convert .storyboard files to objective c .m files?  I've seen several places say that it's possible to convert a storybord using the same command as for an .xib, but there is no output when I try it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should pipe that output to a file whose suffix is `.m`.
You should use this tool like this:

```
./nib2objc TestViewController.xib 2 > TestViewController.m
```

and the output file is `TestViewController.m`

Comment: HI. How to create an environment to run nib2objc?